# Can't insert new input to my form after putting old info in the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form completed with info requested from the database. But the form is not letting me update the form, I can't write anything on the input. What I am using wrong?

After a Graphql query, the title is store in the jsonFromDataBase variable. If the query is empty I want nothing in my input, if it's not, I eant the title but I also want to be able to change it. The problem is that the title is not letting write anything

Here is what my code looks like:

```
   const Form = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
          KeyUtils.resetGenerator();
      }, []); 

       const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState("");  

        return (
            <Title
               type="text"
               value={jsonFromDataBase.title ? jsonFromDataBase.title : newTitle}
               placeholder="Title"
               onChange={e => {
                  setNewTitle(e.target.value);
               }}
               required
            />

       )

  }


  const Title = styled.input`
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid white;
  `;

  export default Form;
```

Comment: How are you getting `jsonFromDataBase.title`? Is `KeyUtils.resetGenerator();` usefull for the answer? Please provide the full code and more explanation

Comment: What is `<Title`? What it does? Same question to `setNewTitle`. We are not magicians we can't ready your mind. Be sure you provide enough info when posting a question.

Comment: @Arseniy-II `setNewTitle` is a react hook defined in this line `const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState(""); `, but yes, `Title` is a mysterious component that needs to be explained

Comment: Sorry, I explained a little better

Answer (score 2):

The problem is controlled vs uncontrolled inputs.

Since you're setting the value from an initial (I assume?) ajax / web query, it appears your `setNewTitle` isn't updating `jsonFromDataBase.title` - or if it is, you'll need to fetch the value again in the onChange handler.

If you want to use a controlled input (ie, handled with `value` and `onChange`) then you should have your initial call to the database fill in the `state` - NOT the value directly.

If you want to use uncontrolled inputs, you can set a default value for the input without changing it to a controlled input by using the `defaultValue` prop, rather than `value`.